# Android Widget animation for ImageView

Tags: android, android-widget

I have one Widget with сouple of `TextViews` and one `ImageView`. Whenever user click on the `ImageView` I am refreshing widget data in the background. This process takes some time. Meanwhile, I want to show small custom animated loader in the `ImageView` place.

For `ImageView` click I use the following statement on the widget:

```
 Views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ImageView, loadIntent);
```

Could anyone guide me how to implement this functionality?

[image]

Comment: Please include the code you've tried

Comment: Thanks for you replay. Unfortunately, i do not have any code.I am new to this Widgets concept.
Please click on the text  "enter image description here" under description. 
you can see gif file there. i need loader after click on image as shown in the gif.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take one progress bar in your widget layout

When you receive click event of your refresh button make progress bar's visibility to visible:

```
views.setViewVisibility(R.id.img_refresh, View.GONE);
views.setViewVisibility(R.id.pb_widget, View.VISIBLE);
```

After your process complete for refreshing data make image visible and progress bar to gone:

```
views.setViewVisibility(R.id.img_refresh, View.VISIBLE);
views.setViewVisibility(R.id.pb_widget, View.GONE);
```